# Find how many common missing (nan) values are in DataFrame columns

Tags: pandas, nan, intersection

I have got DataFrame with about 20 columns and 50000 rows. Small part of this Pandas table is below:

[image]

I am looking for some way to count how many missing values are in the same positions (rows) in a few columns.
When number of the columns is known simply code like these:

```
((df['HomeRemote'].isnull() & df['CompanySize'].isnull()).sum()
```

probably is the answer, but unfortunately number of the columns to compare could be more than 2. I don't know it, because it depends on situation and that's why I looking for something like "universal" solution (working for any number of columns).

My idea is finding a way to "push" every `df[col].isnull()` into the FOR loop (where `col` is name of column), but I have a problem with put '&' between every `df[col].isnull()`.

Maybe anyone here have some other possibility to consider?

If something is not clear enough, please let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

Sample input:

```
>>> df
     A    B    C    D    E
0  NaN  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0
1  NaN  NaN  NaN  1.0  1.0
2  1.0  1.0  1.0  NaN  1.0
3  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  NaN
4  1.0  1.0  NaN  1.0  1.0
5  NaN  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0
6  1.0  1.0  1.0  NaN  1.0
7  1.0  NaN  1.0  NaN  1.0
8  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0
9  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0
```

How many missing values are in the same position in columns A, B, C:

```
>>> df[['A', 'B', 'C']].isnull().all(axis=1).sum()
1
```

Step by step:

```
# Find missing values
>>> df[['A', 'B', 'C']].isnull()
       A      B      C
0   True  False  False
1   True   True   True  # <- HERE
2  False  False  False
3  False  False  False
4  False  False   True
5   True  False  False
6  False  False  False
7  False   True  False
8  False  False  False
9  False  False  False

# Reduce
>>> df[['A', 'B', 'C']].isnull().all(axis=1)
0    False
1     True  # <- HERE
2    False
3    False
4    False
5    False
6    False
7    False
8    False
9    False
dtype: bool

# Reduce again
>>> df[['A', 'B', 'C']].isnull().all(axis=1).sum()
1
```